# Provding dependencies of scope "provided" for a webapp that will run in tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, dependencies

The description for the "provided" scope of maven dependencies contains this note:

> "For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise
>   Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related
>   Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides
>   those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and
>   test classpath, and is not transitive."

Question is if there is a xml snippet available (maybe an official one) that gives me the "provided" dependencies for a specific tomcat version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is a [Bill of Materials (BOM)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies). This can be imported in the `dependencyManagement` section of your `pom.xml` by setting the `type` and the `scope` of the dependency to `pom` and `import`, respectively.

Unfortunately, Tomcat does not seem to provide an official BOM for its provided dependencies. There is an [unofficial version](https://github.com/ghusta/tomcat-provided-spec-bom) on Github, but depending on what you want to use it for, this may not be the best solution. According to the docs at github, you can us it like this:

> ```
> <dependencyManagement>
>     <dependencies>
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>fr.husta.tomcat</groupId>
>             <artifactId>tomcat-provided-spec-bom</artifactId>
>             <version>8.0</version>
>             <type>pom</type>
>             <scope>import</scope>
>         </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
> </dependencyManagement>
> ```

When you use a full-blown JavaEE-Server like JBoss EAP, official BOMs are provided, e. g. [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.bom/eap-runtime-artifacts/7.0.0.GA).